# How to deploy laravel Application so that url doesn't contain '/public/index'

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel application which contain an index file in its public folder which I can access using the following url:

`myIpAddress/teamsync/public/index`

But I want to use url like this:

`myIpAddress/teamsync` to access my index file.

Comment: The idea is that the `public` folder is actually the root of your site, and the other folder sit outside of that.

Comment: What server will your Laravel app be deployed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the best way to remove `/public/...` is to set up your virtual host configuration file to set up the `/public` directory as the document root. This kills two birds with one stone by allowing you to set yoursitename.com as Laravel's root, but also moving sensitive back-end files up away from the `www` root folder.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myserver
    DocumentRoot /var/www/yourproject/public
    ServerAlias www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Examples on how to use virtual hosts:

- With Apache: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html
- With Nginx: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-nginx-virtual-hosts-server-blocks-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts--3